# What is this long black Nintendo DS thing?

Tags: nintendo-ds, hardware

I can't seem to figure out what this is. I know at one point I bought it at one point because I needed it for something but I can't really remember but I know it was important. It looks like a cartridge extender or something. I haven't seen it in about four years so I honestly can't remember. I tried searching on Google but I didn't have any luck. It sort of looks like an adapter but this is for the DS Lite so I don't know what it'd be adapting.

Edit: I did a search for ROM/flash cards and I can't seem to find anything thats what I have. Just R4 cards.

Edit: here's an image I found which appears to have what I have. It's apparently a ROM/homebrew thing. I do remember getting it at Gamestop so I don't know why I got it: [image: 1]

And here's what I have

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: Looks to me like an action replay or game genie type thing. If you bought it from gamestop, they do sell those sorts of things.

Comment: @TrentHawkins an action replay that's it! Could you add that as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks to be an Action Replay. You insert it into your system, and then a game into the Action Replay. Typically allows for cheating in games and copying save files.

Gamestop often sells them, whereas I've not seen them sell flash carts.

Answer (score 2):

It looks very much like the [Action Replay unit for DS and DS Lite](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000H5UY72):
[image: Action Replay in box]
[image: Action Replay unit with disc and cable]
 There's a [Wikipedia article about the action replay series.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Replay)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an adapter for microSD used for playing pirated or ROM dumped games.

Comment: I don't think I was that sophisticated when I was 10 years old but maybe. Also microSD is micro. It wouldn't fit. And I'm pretty sure I wasn't pirating.

Comment: It's not an adapter for MicroSD cards. There isn't even a MicroSD slot!